# how to update gallery after moving photo programmatically?

Tags: android, photo-gallery

I am moving photo from on directory to another using following code

```
File oldfile= new File(originalImagePath);              
File newfile=new File(newImagePath);
boolean d=oldfile.renameTo(newfilee);
if(d){

sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://" + newfilee.getPath())));
 }
```

photos moved to new directory successfully but it take too long time when photos are more in count to update gallery and gallery updates after around 30 seconds or more So give me suggestion what I should do if logic to update file using sendBroadcast is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

to remove from gallery

```
try {

  getContentResolver().delete();

   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, can be replaced Uri.parse(....) with uri of inserted image:           ````java
     getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);````

Comment: welcome, yes you can also pass uri of inserted image.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
    mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
else {
    MediaScannerConnection
            .scanFile(
                    mContext,
                    new String[]{imageFile.toString()},
                    null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(
                                String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned "
                                    + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri="
                                    + uri);
                        }
                    });
}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add a short explanation as to why or how this helps.

Comment: Works for me.. Thanks!! :-)